# Как одним запросом достать список пользоателей БД с их правами и т.д.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть Microsoft sql server 2014 В котором есть пользователи (Admin, user, и так далее).

Я смог отобразить список пользователей при помощи запроса

```
select * from master.sys.server_principals
```

Но вот проблема я не могу узнать какие у них права, статусы и всё такое.
Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно достать полную информацию о логинах и какой способ редактирования лучше

Comment: Если они лежат в других таблицах, то с помощью sql inner join

Comment: @НикитаПавлов Логично, но в каких?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database